# removing words based on a predefined vector

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have the dataset test_stopword and I want to remove some words from the dataset based on a vector. How can I do that in R?

```
texts <- c("This is the first document.", 
       "Is this a text?", 
       "This is the second file.", 
       "This is the third text.", 
       "File is not this.") 

test_stopword <- as.data.frame(texts)
ordinal_stopwords  <- c("first","primary","second","secondary","third")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
texts <- c("This is the first document.", 
       "Is this a text?", 
       "This is the second file.", 
       "This is the third text.", 
       "File is not this.") 

test_stopword <- as.data.frame(texts)
ordinal_stopwords  <- c("first","primary","second","secondary","third")

(newdata <- as.data.frame(sapply(texts, function(x)   gsub(paste(ordinal_stopwords, collapse = '|'), '', x))))
```

The output is getting skewed when added in a code block ([maybe a bug in SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270069/302377)). But, you would get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you. How can I do the replacement on the same dataset?

Comment: You can simply replace `newdata` with `test_stopword`

Comment: It doesn't work. it creates a new column and puts the old column in row.names.

Comment: @HamidehIraj Oh!  Okay. You want to replace the existing one with the new ones, right? It's just a small tweak in that function :)   Anyway, I'll edit the answer in a while. I'm travelling!

Comment: In addition, I have test_stopword$texts not texts vector, so I am looking for something that works on the dataframe.